# jQuery method for hiding a div upon checking another radio button

Tags: jquery, radio-button, pseudo-class, checked

I'm using the code, below, to show or hide a div upon the pseudoclass ":checked" added to an input (in my case checkboxes and radio buttons). Currently, it works perfectly with the checkboxes (the showing/hiding of the div toggles correctly) however, once clicking a radio button, the div will show, but will not hide when clicking on a different radio button.

Here's [a JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HRgDR/).

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Hide hospitalInfo DIV
        $("#hospitalInfo").css("display","none");
        // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
        $(".hospCheck").click(function(){
            // If checked
            if ($(".hospCheck").is(":checked")) {
                //show the hidden div
                $("#hospitalInfo").show("fast");
            } else {
                //otherwise, hide it
                $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <input type="radio" name="ini_disposition" value="H" class="hospCheck" />
    <input type="radio" name="ini_disposition" value="S" />
    <input type="radio" name="ini_disposition" value="T" />

    <input type="checkbox"  class="hospCheck" name="er" value="Y">
    <input type="checkbox"  class="hospCheck" name="er" value="N">
    <div id="hospitalInfo">
      Text I want to hide or show.
    </div>
```

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the click function, don't you want to reference $(this) instead of $(".hospCheck")? This would then reference the specific radio button that was clicked on.

EDIT: Does this fiddle do what you want?  http://jsfiddle.net/kvyZa/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide hospitalInfo DIV
    $("#hospitalInfo").css("display","none");
    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
    $(".hospCheck").click(function(){
        // If checked
        if ($(".hospCheck").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#hospitalInfo").show("fast");
        } else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
        }
    });
    $(".hospCheck1").click(function(){
        // If checked
        if ($(".hospCheck1").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#hospitalInfo").show("fast");
        } else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
        }
    });
    $(".hospCheck2").click(function(){
          $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
    });
});
```

EDIT 2:
Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Aevs/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide hospitalInfo DIV
    $("#hospitalInfo").css("display","none");
    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id checkme
    $(".hospCheck").click(function(){
        // If checked
        if ($(".hospCheck").is(":checked") || $(".hospCheck1").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#hospitalInfo").show("fast");
        } else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
        }
    });
    $(".hospCheck1").click(function(){
        // If checked
        if ($(".hospCheck").is(":checked") || $(".hospCheck1").is(":checked")) {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#hospitalInfo").show("fast");
        } else {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
        }
    });
    $(".hospCheck2").click(function(){
          $("#hospitalInfo").hide("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: To be more more precise, yes it looks better. However, it does not resolve the underlying issue.

Comment: Almost. If the radio button is selected, then click one of the checkboxes, the div remains visible. However, UNchecking one of those boxes (but leaving the correct radio button selected) hides the div, even though it should still be visible (since the radio button that is on should show the div, too.)

Comment: Yep, that one worked. Thanks. The code above, though, is a bit more elegant. But +1 for coming up with a good one!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the class hospCheck to all the radio buttons.

Comment: All that succeeds in doing is to trigger the hide/show on ALL radio buttons. I need it for only ONE of them, and hide on clicking the others. The checkbox is a good example, as it hides/shows based on it being 'checked' or not. However, it seems that once a radio button is 'checked' it always remains that way, according to jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

when clicking another radio button the function isn't called.
use

```
$("input[name='ini_disposition']").click(function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".hospCheck").click(function(){
```

Comment: I think you are right, and that is along the lines of what I was looking for. However, your code does not accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

Look to Van Dessels (now named Yordi) answer, but add the name='er'

```
$("input[name='ini_disposition'], input[name='er']").click(function () {
```

as well. Or do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mbNTL/

```
$("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]").click(function () {
```

Does that help?

Comment: Trying it out in JSFiddle, it seems to work. I can't figure out why, though. Not that you need to explain it to me. I'll figure it out (I think!) As long as it is working, though, I'm in good shape. Thanks!

Comment: Your first try didn't add the onclick function to the two radio buttons that should trigger the hide, only to the elements with the hospCheck class. So nothing would be checked when you clicked them!

Comment: Van Dessels answer is no longer there. I'm not sure which of these on the page to mark as the right answer! Yours got me the closest.

Comment: Van Dessel changed name to Yordi in the mean time :)